# Is there a way to have different clause inside the @Where annotation depending on profiles/database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Working on a Spring Boot project, I had the following situation:

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class MyEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinColumns( {
            @JoinColumn(name = "..."),
            @JoinColumn(name = "...")
    })
    @Where(clause = "\"COLUMN\" = 'inputport'")
    private List<Port> inputPorts = new ArrayList<Port>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinColumns( {
            @JoinColumn(name = "..."),
            @JoinColumn(name = "...") 
    })
    @Where(clause = "\"COLUMN\" = 'outputport'")
    private List<Port> outputPorts = new ArrayList<Port>();
    
    // Rest of the code ...

}
```

I'm looking for a way, even complex, to use different name for COLUMN (i.e., "\"COLUMN\"" or "COLUMN", where the former is for PostgreSql and H2 and the latter for MySql) depending on the active profile or the database (we have different profiles for different database).

Every idea will be appreciated, even ideas where the code will be completely different.

As a requirement, I'm not allowed to work on a DB level, so I can't change DDLs.

Thanks

I tried with custom annotations, interceptors, working on the properties file level, but I'm still unable to achieve the desired result.

Comment: hello! could you try to update the annotation using reflection? check out this article https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params